# Redirect link if 404 error appears

Tags: java, javascript, android, ajax, url-scheme

### Problem Description

I am writing Android application and I need to add to my application some functionality, when user open standard web browser in Android and navigate to me web page (http://mywebpage.com) and there press on some button (Test Button) web page must detect if my application is already installed on the Android phone.

### What I do to solve this problem

I have read many articles and ask here some questions and I understand that I can't do something in order my web page can understand if My Application is installed on the phone or not, the one thing that I can do it write some code in the manifest file

```
<a href="my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
</intent-filter>
```

But this is not enough for me as if application is not installed on the phone when user press on the link in my web site it give an 404 error saying that there is no such URL `my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here` I want to find another solution for this and here what I think.

### Solution for the problem

How I can throw some exception from my web site when user press on the link `<a href="my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here">` and it show 404 error. I mean can I make some AJAX or JAVA Script calls in order to determine that url refer to not valid link and redirect to another link in that case.

### Solution for the problem 2

I use intent filter like this

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="commonsware.com" android:path="LaunchApp"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and place a link on a web page like this

```
<a href="commonsware.com/LaunchApp">Start App</a>.
```

### Question

How I can redirect to the URL which I specify when the real URL does not exist or it give 404 error. Please provide me an examples as I am not strong in AJAX and JAVA Script coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something like that, based on this answer of Diane Hackborn [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/s0DGBknT11o/ehHDOSi1_5wJ):

> Please don't use a scheme unless it is one that you have registered. 
>   Schemes are global to the universe, and since you will be putting this
>   out in the universe via your web page you want to follow the rules for
>   them.
>
> Another approach you can take is to just create an Intent that you
>   want to have launched, and print the result of Intent.toUri() to get
>   the string to use in your link.  (This should be an intent: URI.) 
>   Then you probably want to just make your own action following the
>   standard naming conventions which that Intent will use.  You can even
>   use Intent.setPackage() to make sure that only your app can be
>   launched from the link, if you want.  (Do note you can't use
>   Intent.setComponent() for this for security reasons.)

I built an Intent as to launch the desired activity and then, as described, converted the Intent to an URI and printed that to stdout. This URI (it starts with `intent:` as a scheme) I used in my web-page like so:

`<a href="intent:/...">Start App</a>`.

This will start the Activity, if the Application is installed, otherwise it brings up the Play-Store App, already showing the App's page (if found in the Play-Store, that is) for the User to download and install.

Comment: Is this method work if my application is not installed on the phone ?

Comment: @ViToBrothers Yes. That's the whole point of the question :-) The intent: protocol is understood by the Android OS, and it checks if there's any Activity registered for this intent and if so, it is started, otherwise the Play-Store app is launched.

Comment: I place the link on my web site but when I click it on it from my Phones browser when my application was not installed it show 404 error

Comment: here is the link http://alumtrans.com/ to my site I place url on Test when I click on Test it shows 404 error

Comment: @ViToBrothers Don't create a pseudo-intent-link yourself. Really do as I explained: In your app, create an Intent and set it up as you would to start your Activity from within the app. Then, use the result of the intent's toUri() method for your link. The link looks quite weired, it has the package name etc. in it.

Comment: And if I have no installed app on my phone ?

Comment: In order to create the correct intent:/... link you'll somehow have to create at least a tiny app so that you can create the Intent and do the toUri() trick. You can also run that app in the emulator if you like, but you'll need that. After you have the correct link you can remove the app from your phone if you like.

Comment: @Ridcullu so it mean that I must have installed app on a phone to do that .... Lets imagine situation if I never instal application on a phone and press on a link Test. I want browser show play store in that case and do not show 404 error ? You understand whole problem ?

Comment: I have download an example from the [link](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler/) install it and go to the web site [commonsware.com](http://commonsware.com/sample) when I click on 'Link back to URLHandler via intent: URL' when my application was installed application opened, but when I click on the same link when my applications is not installed it shows 404 ERROR !!!!

Comment: How can you make an app and never install it on a device? Do you not want to test it?

Comment: look I have install application and RUN it. go to [cmmonsware.com](http://commonsware.com/sample) and everything works fine !!! when I press on links in browser my application opens !!! BUT WHEN I UNINSTALL APPLICATION AND GO TO same web page and click on the links web browser SHOWS 404 ERROR !!! AND DO NOTHING !!!! YOU UNDERSTAND ??? It do not open ant android store or something else it just say 404 ERROR !!!!

Comment: in your post you write that "This will start the Activity, if the Application is installed, otherwise it brings up the Play-Store App, already showing the App's page (if found in the Play-Store, that is) for the User to download and install." but it is not true. If application is not installed it open 404 error page.

Comment: "BUT WHEN I UNINSTALL APPLICATION AND GO TO same web page and click on the links web browser SHOWS 404 ERROR !!!" -- there is no redirect on `intent:` schemes. Purchase a domain name. Put up a Web site on that domain name. Use a `<data>` element tying your app to a URL on that domain. Put up a Web page at that URL to handle the case where your app is not installed. Put a link to that URL wherever you want. Now, if the app is installed, the user will have a choice to run that app; if the app is not installed, the user will see your Web page.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please provide me an example ? I must use URL instead of scheme like this '<data android:scheme="http" android:host="commonsware.com"/>' ? "Put up a Web page at that URL to handle the case where your app is not installed." Can I place URL to the Play store and if application is not installed Play store will be opened ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I try to place Android Store Url on my web page <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fullfat.android.agentdash">Start App</a> and write following line in manifest <data android:scheme="https" android:host="play.google.com" android:path="/store/apps/details?id=com.fullfat.android.agentdash" /> but it doesn't work I think the reason is ? in the manifest path. Am I right ?